# Android how to center an EditText dynamically

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, android-relativelayout, center

**Goal**

I have a RelativeLayout with some TextView's sets in xml and I want to add dynamically some EditText's, one below another.

**Problem**

How can I center horizontally those EditText's?

**Code**

Here is my code up to date:

```
/* Layout with EditText's */
RelativeLayout parentLayout = (RelativeLayout)
findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutLectura);
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
// If it's first EditText to insert, goes below another linearLayout set before
if(id == -1) {
    editText.setId(1);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.linearLayoutMensajeLectura);
} else {
    editText.setId(id);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, id-1);
}
editText.setLayoutParams(params);
editText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); //It does nothing
parentLayout.addView(editText);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your EditText's to container (like LinearLayout), then add this container to your parent RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the gravity of the edit text will effect where the text is displayed inside it.

As you're putting it into a RelativeLayout, you need to `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT)` or `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)`